# What does the @font-face folder contain when I downloaded a font off the internet?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've downloaded a font off some site, when I extracted the zip folder, I got 2 folders:

[image]

The Lulo clean folder has a .ttf file which I believe contains the actual font.
The @font-face folder has a bunch of cryptic file names:

[image]

Why exactly is the @font-face folder required? Will the font still load even if I delete it?

Also an additional question, I've tried using a google font in my website, it comes with the option to include the font in my site either by using link html tag or by downloading the font,why would anyone want to load the font using link tag? Isn't it just better to download instead because if google fonts is down for whatever reason, then the font wont load?